# Global Controller/Method in Objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, usersession

I'm building an iPhone App which requires to be logged in all the time. Now I don't know if there is a global place to put in something like:

> If not_logged_in -> go to LoginView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can write this `if-else` statement in `- applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.**

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"LoggedIn"])
{
    // User already Logged In.
}
else
{
    // Go to Login View.
}
```

**In your `loginViewController`, after Successful Login add this line :**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"LoggedIn"];
```